# Changing displaying layout on button click

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, button

I have a custom circle layout with rotation feature and 4 views as buttons.
On main_activity i have 2 layouts :
-circle layout
-relative layout(Container)

What i want is:
-when the user taps on a button from circle layout, i want the container to be changed with another layout with another views.

This is the initialization of container:

```
displayLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
```

Initialization of Circle layout:

```
circleLayout = (CircleLayout) findViewById(R.id.circle_layout);
```

The tap event occurs on this method:

```
    public void onItemClick(View view) {

    displayLayout.removeAllViews();
     -- What should i do here? --
}
```

I want that the new xml (newpage.xml) to be replaced in container.

Any sugestions to be done?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: use fragment concept as frame layout & replace content with fragment manager

Comment: You should use fragments. Else a quicker option is short run is to toggle visibility of multiple layouts, using GONE/VISIBLE based on conditions (but this will be a headache in long run)

Comment: Any easy and good tutorial that fits on my example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between 2 layouts in android activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017428/switching-between-2-layouts-in-android-activity)

Comment: Yeah, i think i made a dupe ^^ but thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do it with **fragments** as shown in below, to replace view

check fragments in android(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

```
public void onItemClick(View view) {
        //displayLayout.removeAllViews();
        // Create new fragment and transaction
        Fragment newFragment = new ExampleFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

check http://sapandiwakar.in/replacing-fragments/

check example http://notionink.wikidot.com/rajeshbabu

Comment: removing the circlelayout isn't the actual problem. I want circlelayout to be on top of the other layouts. what i actually want is changing the container layout with another on button click.

Comment: do you want to change at runtime ?

Comment: On itemclick method. At the first load, displayLayout has 3 Textviews, on button click i want to put displayLayout2 with n different views.

Comment: than use fragments for that.

Comment: i tried with ViewFlipper and it worked, but i'll try with fragment too :D THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

replace code here ,

```
public void onItemClick(View view) {

  //  displayLayout.removeAllViews();
  circleLayout.setVisibility(View.Gone);

}
```