# how can i switch other fragment layout programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I' ve got two layouts (layout_first.xml and layout_second.xml).
I want to show layout_second, after click a Button (Show Second) in layout_first. And get an EditText value in the layout_first to set EditText value in the layout_second programmaticaly. How can i do this? Thanks for your answers.

my codes:

activity_main.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/custom_tab_layout_height"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

layout_first.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#bc8383"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Second"
        android:id="@+id/btnShowSecond"
        android:layout_weight="0.18" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:text="et1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#85b27e"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout_second.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:background="#bc8383">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et2"
        android:text="et2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:elegantTextHeight="false"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#85b27e"
        android:textSize="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="btn2"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

custom_tab.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tab"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@string/font_fontFamily_medium"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        TextView tabOne = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabOne.setText("One");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(tabOne);

        TextView tabTwo = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_tab, null);
        tabTwo.setText("Two");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(tabTwo);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new First(), "One");
        adapter.addFrag(new Second(), "Two");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }
}
```

Second.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Second extends Fragment {
    public Second() {
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_second, container, false);

        String data = getArguments().getString("value");
        et2.setText(data);

        return view;
    }
}
```

First.java

```
package xmaxsoft.delfragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class First extends Fragment {
    public First() {
    }

    Button btnShowSecond;
    EditText et1;

public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.aid1, fragment, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_first, container, false);
        btnShowSecond = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnShowSecond);
        et1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et1);
        btnShowSecond.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???
            //what kind of code must be here ???

            Second myfragment = new Second();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("value",et1.getText().toString());
            myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
            Activity.addFragment(myfragment, false,"Second");//error ??? cannot resolve method ???


            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

How can i display or switch layout_second programmatically in layout_first? Thank you for your helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching between 2 layouts in android activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7017428/switching-between-2-layouts-in-android-activity)

Comment: No i use fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using Intent class.
1. on First.java put this code in **clicklistener**

```
public void mybutton_click()
{
  Second myfragment = new Second();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("value",et1.getText());
    myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
    activity.addFragment(myfragment, false,
            "Second");
}
```

To call other Fragment

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack,
        String tag) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

    if (addToBackStack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(tag);
    }
    ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag);
    ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

2. In Second.java put this on **Oncreate()**:

   ```
     String data = getArguments().getString("value");
     et2.setText(data);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but took error in First.java: cannot resolve constuctor 'Intent xmaxsoft.delfragment.First, java.lang.Class<xmaxsoft.delfragment.Second>)'

Comment: And in Second.java i got an error too: cannot resolve method getIntent() and cannot resolve method getExtra

Comment: Yes as you are using Fragment . Let me update my code

Comment: put addFragment method in class which extends ActionBarBaseActivitiy

Comment: thank you for your helps but doesn't work. in addFragment method i've got errors R.anim.slide_in_right (there is no slide_in_right there it affects an error) and Activity.addFragment(myfragment, false,"Second");//can not resolve method error and ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag); //there is no content_frame intellisense there. they are red.

Comment: give android:id R.id.content_frame to Linearlayout of First.java and remove animations call.

Comment: Thank you again. I've updated my codes according your advices. But still one more error ======> Activity.addFragment(myfragment, false,"Second");//error ??? cannot resolve method ??? would you please check it again. Thanks. addFragment is RED

Comment: activity is object of class where this "addFragment(..)" declared. remove activity if you have declared it in same class.

Comment: thank you again... i replace Activity.addFragment to just addFragment but it doesnt work properly. it is mixed controls there. and i dont want to replace fragment just switch.

Comment: and in Second.Java  this lines causes stop because null exception error ===>       String data = getArguments().getString("value");