# Switch between layouts within a single activity

Tags: android

I'm new to android develeopment and I'm trying to switch between different layouts using a single Activity class.

I'm able to view the second layout, but onclick of make it rain button, the app crashes.

I get the error **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTextColor(int)' on a null object reference**

Here is what I tried out

[image]

[image]
[image]

How do i resolve this?

Sorry, I couldn't post the code as it is due to some reasons.

Comment: You better launch new activity or fragment

Comment: @dywp of course I can do that, but i was just wondering, how to do it without it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7017428/10022404

Comment: @HackersInside Do you have `moneyText` `Textview` in both the `xmls`

Comment: @Keshav1234 yes I figured out that i didnt have it in the first layout. Resolved. Thanks mate.

Comment: @HackersInside Glad you were able to fix it, Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have the text view moneyText in the first view. Hence i was getting the error.

Resolved it by finding it in the method related to Make it rain button.

[image]